# Accept post data VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-upload

I'm working with vb.net and have a form posting data: value1 is text, value2 is an image.

How can I decode the multipart form-data coming to the server, save the file and pass the text to another function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the picture:

```
Dim pix As HttpPostedFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files("pix")
```

For form element:

```
Dim pix As HttpPostedFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("tag")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, ASP.NET does this for you and makes the data available via the `Request.Form` collection, with items indexed by key. Uploaded files are exposed via `Request.Files` instead of `Request.Form`.

```
String value1 = Request.Form["value1"];
HttpPostedFile image = Request.Files["value2"];
```

Comment: I'm using VB.NET when formatted for VB it says "Form is not a member of Request.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage"

Comment: What platform are you using? `HttpRequestMessage` is for writing HTTP clients, not servers (that's `System.Web.HttpRequest`). It doesn't like like you're using ASP.NET.